# Servlets with RTC

Tags: java, servlets, rtc

Does anyone know if it is possible to do implement servlets using the RTC Java API ? My goal is to do a web page which connects to rtc and retrieves a snapshot desired by the user.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more for the servlet classes you can write to call the 
[Rational Team Concert plain Java API's](https://jazz.net/library/article/1229), not the reverse.

In other words, that API doesn't know about [Java EE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition), but nothing prevents your Java EE app to use RTC java API.

Make sure you [don't call TeamPlatform.shutdown() though](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/33413/teamplatformshutdown-cannot-shutdown):

> You need to start the platform the first time the servlet executes, but if you stop it in your servlet code, you'll get the exception when another user calls the servlet.